# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in DocumentsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

A little bit of background. I am trying to pre-populate an attribute of my Document model upon creation. In order to do that I am using a basic form of "current_user" helper.

However, when I try to set `@document.creator = current_user.id` I get a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch ... User expected, got Fixnum` error.

I confess that I am not sure why. Would someone be able to clarify what exactly is incorrect?

The relevant Models and controllers are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authority::UserAbilities
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :authorizations
end
```

and

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "id", primary_key: "creator"
  attr_accessible :document_subject, document_keywords
  def as_json(options={})
    {
        :document_subject => document_subject,
        :document_keywords => document_keywords,
    }
  end
end
```

and

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

and

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @document = Document.new(params[:document])
    @document.creator = current_user.id
    @document.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.save
        format.json { render json: @document, status: :created, location: @document }
      else
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the DB schema (as written to DB)

```
PRAGMA table_info(users);
[,
 {
  "cid": 0,
  "name": "id",
  "type": "INTEGER",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 1
 },
 {
  "cid": 1,
  "name": "name",
  "type": "varchar(255)",
  "notnull": 0,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
 {
  "cid": 2,
  "name": "email",
  "type": "varchar(255)",
  "notnull": 0,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
 {
  "cid": 3,
  "name": "created_at",
  "type": "datetime",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
 {
  "cid": 4,
  "name": "updated_at",
  "type": "datetime",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
 {
  "cid": 5,
  "name": "active",
  "type": "boolean",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": 'f',
  "pk": 0
 }
]

PRAGMA table_info(Documents);

[,
 {
  "cid": 0,
  "name": "id",
  "type": "INTEGER",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 1
 },
 {
  "cid": 1,
  "name": "created_at",
  "type": "datetime",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
 {
  "cid": 2,
  "name": "updated_at",
  "type": "datetime",
  "notnull": 1,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
 {
  "cid": 3,
  "name": "creator",
  "type": "integer",
  "notnull": 0,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
{
  "cid": 4,
  "name": "document_subject",
  "type": "varchar(255)",
  "notnull": 0,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 },
{
  "cid": 5,
  "name": "document_keywords",
  "type": "varchar(255)",
  "notnull": 0,
  "dflt_value": null,
  "pk": 0
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expecting the Active Record object itself instead of the ID. You just need to do `@document.creator = current_user`.

Comment: I had tried it before but I get a undefined method `to_i' for #<User:0x00000004171700>

Comment: are you sure the primary key and foreign key are correct? It seems weird that your foreign key is just "id". Normally it would be something like "user_id" or "creator_id", depending on how your DB is setup.

Comment: I guess so? Added the JSON representation of table_info to the original question.

Comment: Are you sure you want this to be a has_one relationship? If so, you need to have a document_id column on your user table. With that in place, you don't need to specify primary or foreign key options. The alternative is to use belongs_to, and you'd have a user_id column on the Document table.

Comment: IMO, this should probably be belongs_to, not has_one.

Comment: It could be. The reason I went with has_one is because each Document should also have - later on - a reviewer. It seemed to me more natural to have it as "has one creator", "has one reviewer" , than "belong to creator", "belong to reviewer", makes sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40057/discussion-between-andre-de-miranda-and-beerlington)

Answer (score 0):

Beerlington reply worked as described, but still didn't feel like the ideal solution to what I was trying to achieve.

I ended up changing strategies: instead of adding a creator field to the document model I moved to use [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Usage) roles granted upon the creation of the documents using:

```
@document.save
current_user.add_role :creator, @document
```